# C# Strict Int/Float parsing

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm wondering how to implement strict parsing of a string in C#.

Specifically, I want to require that the string contains just the number (in culture-specific format), and no other characters.

```
"1.0"  -> 1.0  
"1.5 " -> fail  
" 1.5" -> fail  
" 1,5" -> fail (if culture is with ".")  
"1,5"  -> fail
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz.aspx) method accepts flags covering certain situations you mention. Have look [into MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) on `NumberStyles` enumeration. Also, it accepts culture-specific formatting information.

Comment: Or in this specific example, Float.Parse or Decimal.Parse.  Any of those methods will accept an IFormatProvider object.  You should be able to pass System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat right into Parse.  Not sure about the white spaces, it may automatically trim.  Not sure why that would be a problem, but it ain't my program. =)

Comment: `NumberStyles` is exactly what provides support for (dis)allowing trailing/leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `Parse`/`TryParse` methods of the `int`, `float` and `double` types. They have [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) that allow specifying a `CultureInfo` and allow restricting the accepted number format:

```
string value = "1345,978";
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
double number;

if (double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

TryParse specifically allows  whitespace before and after the number [Double.TryParse reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx), so it is not strict enough for your requirements unless you explicitly use NumberStyles.